# Check one-on-one relationship between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns A and B in a pandas dataframe, where values are repeated multiple times. For a unique value in A, B is expected to have "another" unique value too. And each unique value of A has a corresponding unique value in B (See example below in the form of two lists). But since each value in each column is repeated multiple times, I would like to check if any one-to-one relationship exists between two columns or not. Is there any inbuilt function in pandas to check that? If not, is there an efficient way of achieving that task?

Example:

```
A = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
B = [5, 12, 12, 10, 5, 10, 5, 5]
```

Here, for each 1 in A, the corresponding value in B is always 5, and nothing else. Similarly, for 2-->10, and for 3-->12. Hence, each number in A has only one/unique corresponding number in B (and no other number). I have called this one-on-one relationship. Now I want to check if such relationship exists between two columns in pandas dataframe or not.

An example where this relationship is not satisfied:

```
A = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
B = [5, 12, 12, 10, 5, 10, 7, 5]
```

Here, 1 in A doesn't have a unique corresponding value in B. It has two corresponding values - 5 and 7. Hence, the relationship is not satisfied.

Comment: pleas provide a sample data.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show us a small sample dataframe and the output you expect from the solution.

Comment: Sample (actually, explanatory example) has been provided now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have some dataframe:

```
 d = df({'A': [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2], 'B': [4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5]})
```

`d` has `groupby` method, which returns [`GroupBy` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). This is the interface to group some rows by equal column value, for example.

```
 gb = d.groupby('A')
 grouped_b_column = gb['B']
```

On grouped rows you could perform an aggregation. Lets find min and max value in every group.

```
res = grouped_b_column.agg([np.min, np.max])

>>> print(res)
   amin  amax
A            
1     4     4
2     5     5
3     6     6
```

Now we just should check that `amin` and `amax` are equal in every group, so every group consists of equal `B` fields:

```
res['amin'].equals(res['amax'])
```

If this check is OK, then for every `A` you have unique `B`. Now you should check the same criteria for `A` and `B` columns swapped.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Be careful if you have `None` values. The behaviour might not be the one you want. For example, it returns `True` for `pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2], 'B': [4, 6, None, 5, 4, 6, 5]})`